# SpringBoot AMQP client gives Channel shutdown: connection error with several tomcat publishers

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, apachebench

We have SpringBoot (1.5.4.RELEASE) controller that services GET requests from memory, logs the fact and also publishes into RMQ (RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()).

We configure our CachingConnectionFactory as follows:

```
...
connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(240); //seconds
connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(600);  //seconds
connectionFactory.setCacheMode(CacheMode.CHANNEL);
connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(32768);
...
```

We bumped up the limit of open file descriptors and processes per user so Tomcat can easily handle > 10 K concurrent requests. However when Tomcat's servicing threads also have to publish into RMQ, we get "Channel shutdown: connection error" from CachingConnectionFactory and then RMQ client starts throwing:

```
    java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
            at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
            at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:95)
            at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(DataOutputStream.java:153)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.writeTo(Frame.java:185)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:171)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.writeFrame(AMQConnection.java:542)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:104)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:337)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:313)
            at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicPublish(ChannelN.java:686)

...
```

This happens when apache bench is used to fire >=5000 concurrent requests.

My question is:

1. Is it too many concurrent producers for AMQP/CachingConnectionFactory (I thought bumping up channel cache size would take of that) ?
2. Could I put something in configuration that could support this use-case ?

This doesn't seem to break because of msg throughput (which stays < 200 msgs/s) but because of the sheer number of concurrent requests/Tomcat publishers.

If, instead of making Tomcat threads publish into RMQ directly, I write into in-memory queue first and let few hundred dedicated RMQ publishers take up from there, I don't get such issues but team fears loosing msgs in such case so have to publish to RMQ in sync with servicing GET request.

Comment: I suggest looking in the RabbitMQ server logs to see if there are any clues there; as you say, having a large enough channel cache should help.

Comment: Do you get a solution for this problem? We have the same and still dont know why it does not work...